# Wamp Server atualizando PHP para versão 7

Tags: laravel-5, wamp, php-7

Boa Noite pessoal, estou com o seguinte problema, eu estou tentando atualizar meu PHP para poder seguir o curso com Laravel mas não estou tendo sucesso.
tenho ambiente :
Windows 10 
Wamp 2.5 
PHP 5.5.12 
Apache 2.4

Andei lendo a documentação Laravel 5 e me deparei com a informação de que a versão mínima do PHP deve ser 5.6.4 para suporte ao Laravel 5. Na configuração citada acima não rola.. preciso atualizar meu PHP.

Fui atras do PHP 7

Fiz uma perquisa mais completa sobre o assunto através Obtive sucesso em fazer Wamp enchergar o novo PHP 7, clicando no icone w-> PHP -> Version, está listano 5.5.12 e 7.0.14, perfeito ate ai :) Mas o problema é que ele não consegue colocar o servidor online. (O ícone 'w' fica sempre laranja) quando escolho a opção da versão 7.

Em Resumo... Baixei o PHP 7.0.14 no site do PHP Extrai o Arquivo zip no caminho "c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.14" Seguir as intruções do link: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?1,133587,133587#msg-133618 criei o arquivo "php.ini", "phpForApache.ini" que são arquivos cópia do "php.ini-development", criei o arquivo "wampserver.conf", todos esses arquivos estão nesse mesmo caminho "c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.14".

Bem agora estou sem idéias de como prosseguir como configurar Wamp para suportar PHP 7.

Arquivo "config.inic.php" localizado no caminho c:/wamp/scripts/config.inic.php pelo que entendi ele é necessário para ativar dlls de versões de phps, permite adicionar novas versões quando necessário.

bem  coloquei os nomes das dlls do php 7 no arquivo mas nada mudou deve haver mais detalhes desconhecidos...
Quem puder me dar uma dica de ajuda ficarei muito grato.

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Eu uso a versão 3.0.6 e funciona o PHP 7(mesmo que não use, ainda). Seu wamp está desatualizado, baixe essa versão - https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10.exe/download

Comment: Mano, desinstala tudo e instala o Wamp com o PHP 7 já embutido.